# IO::Socket:SSL sometimes adds newline when printing on socket

Tags: perl, ssl, server, newline

I have a method that sends a message to a remote SSL server. The class is embedded in a program that may be called from the command line, or the program can be started as a daemon and may call the class method on request. I use [`Net::Server::Fork`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Server::Fork) to launch the daemon:

```perl
package myserver;

use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'Net::Server::Fork';

myserver->run(
    'port'            => $main::config{'backend.ssl.host'} . '/ssl',
    'ipv'             => '*',
    'log_level'       => $main::config{'backend.loglevel'},
    'log_file'        => $main::config{'backend.logfile'},
    'pid_file'        => $main::config{'backend.pidfile'},
    'user'            => $main::config{'backend.user'},
    'group'           => $main::config{'backend.group'},
    'max_servers'     => $main::config{'backend.maxconnections'},
    'background'      => !$main::config{'backend.foreground'},
    'leave_children_open_on_hup' => 1,
    'allow'           => $main::config{'ip'},
    'reverse_lookups' => 1,
    'SSL_key_file'    => $main::config{'backend.ssl.key'},
    'SSL_cert_file'   => $main::config{'backend.ssl.crt'},
    'SSL_ca_file'     => $main::config{'backend.ssl.bundle'},
);

sub process_request {
    # call connect and sendframe if requested
};
```

The external communication class connects with [`IO::Socket::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL) and sends data by prepending the packet length as a 4-byte header and then sends the message as-is:

```perl
package communicator;

use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::SSL;

sub connect {
    my $self   = shift @_;
    my $server = shift @_;
    my @field    = split /\:/, $server;

    my $socket;

    $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
        'PeerAddr' => $field[0],
        'PeerPort' => $field[1],
        'Blocking' => 1,
    );

    if ( $socket ) {
        binmode $socket;
    }
    else {
        # error handling
    };

    $self->{'SOCK'} = $socket;
};

sub sendframe {
    my $self = shift @_;
    my $msg  = shift @_;

    if ($self->{'SOCK'}) {
        my $length = pack("N", bytes($msg));
        ($self->{'SOCK'})->print($length);
        ($self->{'SOCK'})->print($msg);
    };
};
```

This works when called from the command line, but fails when running as a [`Net::Server`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Server) process. I have tried logging the content that is sent to the remote server, but the log files are identical for both approaches.

I have written a minimal SSL server to capture the content, and found out that when `Net::Server` is running, each print on a socket adds a newline to what is being sent. So the server receives

```
[packet length in binary]Line 1
Line 2
--- [Received announced length + 4 bytes]
```

on a direct call and

```
[packet length in binary]
Line 1
Line 2

--- [Received announced length + 6 bytes]
```

on a call with `Net::Server` running. Of course this breaks communication with the external server.

I suspect that `Net::Server` sets a global config variable in `IO::Socket::SSL` that confuses subsequent calls to `sendframe`, but I cannot figure out which variable it might be.

**Note that** I am using an external library to connect to other servers in addition to my own `communicator` class. That library also uses `IO::Socket::SSL` and suffers from the same issue, so I'd prefer to fix `IO::Socket::SSL` over using something other than `$socket->print`.

I would be able to patch the external library, but would likely have to do that every time there is an update.

My system is Debian 7 with Perl 5.14, IO::Socket::SSL 2.020 and Net::Server 2.006

Comment: Your packages (and the modules' filenames) should be capitalised, so `MyServer.pm` and `Communicator.pm`. Also, are you aware that all of those hash keys need no quotes? `reverse_lookups => 1` is fine.

Comment: In reality the package names start with an uppercase letter, sorry for the confusion. I prefer to have quotes around hash keys for better syntax highlighting, though.

Comment: Tip: `print(pack("N", bytes($msg)); print(bytes($msg));` can be reduced to `print(pack("N", bytes($msg)), bytes($msg));` and even to `print(pack("N/a*", bytes($msg)));` (This also makes it obvious that you're missing a call to `bytes`!)

Comment: Re "*for better syntax highlighting*", That makes them look like strings when they actually serve the purpose of identifiers. That's exactly why you *shouldn't* use quotes.

Comment: Update: I found out that any `say` called when `Net::Server` is running sets `\$ ` to "\n", so any `print` or `say` after the first say prints an additional newline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` on an IO::Socket::SSL handle behaves like `print` on other file handles in that it respects the setting of `$\`. From `perldoc perlvar`:

```
  $\      The output record separator for the print operator.  
          If defined, this value is printed after the last of print's
          arguments.  Default is "undef".
```

Since this variable is undef by default there will only be changes if somebody sets this variable explicitly. I cannot see Net::Server set this variable anywhere. Maybe it's instead in your own code or other modules you use? In case you will not affect your other code you could localize the variable, i.e.

```
if ($self->{'SOCK'}) {
    local $\ = undef; ### make sure to disable side effects
    my $length = pack("N", bytes($msg));
    ($self->{'SOCK'})->print($length);
    ($self->{'SOCK'})->print($msg);
};
```

Comment: This seems like a solid reason for the misbehaviour. @Marcus: can you test for this please?

Comment: Or use `->printf("%s", ...)`

Comment: @ikegami: or just `->syswrite(...)`

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, I don't think `syswrite` is guaranteed to write the whole buffer (especially when writing to a socket), so you'd need a loop. That's far more complicated.

Comment: @ikegami: that's true, you need to check the return code to find out how much was transferred.

Comment: That's it, $\ was set to "\n". Never would have guessed, thanks guys! Can't locate where this is set, though, but that's a different story.